# Built Android App with Jenkins including Library Projects

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, build-automation

I have just set-up my local jenkins installation on my mac...

Now i have tried to create an ant built which builds my app as soon as i check-in a new change. The ant script is working great as long as i only use it in the project...

- cd into the folder
- ant release

It is able to find all library projects i'Ve included (ActionBarSherlock, ViewPagerIndicator, NineOldAndroids, HoloEveryWhere, PocketChange)

As soon as i put this on my jenkins installation everything breaks.

My main folder-organisation is like this:
Projects/Project
Projects/ProjectLibrarys/Library
Eclipse referes to those libraries like this: android.library.reference.2=../Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library

I can't use absolute links (because i think they will fix the issue) but eclipse or ant doesn't like them.

I have really no idea how to fix it?
Will i have to edit the build.xml (i've added it into the folder ext/commonbuild/commonbuild.xml so i have the same android build file for all my projects)

If you need more code let me know.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i was able to solve my issue by adding a customproject.properties file with a seperate link for the build.

There is still one issue. It seems that ant doesn't use the customproject.properties for my library project i've added. This library project includes another library project and as soon as i build it has a wrong relative url.

Does someone know how to use the customproject.properties even for the project libraries?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - can't build in jenkins regular android project which uses other  android library project. It works manually "ant" but not in Jenkins. Can you write exactly what did you do?

Comment: The main problem is that the paths are different in jenkins / eclipse. The project.properties contains relativ paths and jenkins won't find the projects in the same relativ path. A solution is to add a customproject.properties (used through a custom build.xml) and set custom paths. (I use and via terminal now, because the whole set-up process was to much work, and it's easy enough to do it via my terminal too, so i would say stay with terminal for now and wait (like i) for a better build-solution ;))

Comment: I resolved the problem by checkouting two modules from the git - and than the Android project also can access Android Library Project - no changes in code :)

Answer (score 1):

As bluszcz mentioned, I checked out two modules and i was able to build my apk via Jenkins without having two project.properties or customproject.properties file.

On Jenkins Configure Screen, Under Source Code Management - Subversion Modules,

1. Give the url for your android project (say, SampleAndroidProject)
   https://goxxx.com/svn/repository/projects/trunk/SampleAndroidProject
2. Provide local module directory as 'SampleAndroidProject'
3. Provide the svn url for your library project (say, google-play-services_lib)
   https://goxxx.com/svn/repository/projects/trunk/google-play-services_lib
4. Provide local module directory as 'google-play-services_lib'

Save and build again.